# Someone has asked me if the sentence should read 'depend on' or 'depends on' Which is correct?

Tags: verbs

everyone's working relationships and success depend/s on people ....

Should it be depend on or depends on?

I thought it should be depends, but someone else wrote depend.

Comment: You could make your question better if you explained why you think it is "depends"  What grammar rule are you applying here?

Answer (score 1):

It depends () on how many things are doing the depending. So it's just like most other verbs. For example:

More than one thing (i.e. plural; third person plural to be precise)

> Tom, Dick, and Harry *walk* to Starbucks every morning.

Just one thing (i.e. singular; third person singular to be precise)

> Sally *walks* to Starbucks every morning.

Of course English is rarely *that* simple, and your sample sentence is an example of that. So, what we need to decide is:

When it comes to the following:

> …everyone's working relationships and success…

Is it singular? If it is, then the correct choice is "depends".
Or is it plural? If so, then the correct choice is "depend".

In fact, in everyday use, native speakers might choose either. Obviously it can be seen as plural -- we clearly could be talking about two things: working relationships is one, and success is the other. But it wouldn't be incorrect to regard those two as one composite thing. Context might make one or the other a more obvious choice, but in most cases it won't matter.

Conclusion: both of you are right; either of "depend" or "depends" works.